# InteliJ+Typescript: Variable Declaration Expected Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, expo

[image]

This is expo ReactNative App. Able to build and run the app using

```
expo start
```

However, InteliJ Flags this file as having an error and all this file has is the above referenced code

```
import { ButtonActionTypes } from "../types/ButtonTypes";
import { Action } from "redux";

export const incrementCount = (): Action<string> => {
    return {
        type: ButtonActionTypes.Increment
    }
};
```

How do I get rid of this error so the project in InteliJ looks clean?

Comment: Sometimes intellij bugs out and shows invalid errors. If the code compile then I would chalk it up to that.  Its possible you could have a typescript version mismatch.

Comment: can't see any errors reported for this code; does restarting the typescript compiler service help?